# dependency management and release lifecycle in dotnet

Tags: .net, release-management, dependency-management

Recently my team has hit the wall while trying to manage dependencies semi-automatically. 
You know, the trunk/lib folder in svn with a ci-server that commits fresh versions of dlls into that folder. But migration of one of the projects from svn to git exposed the problem that repository is growing too fast and we are trying to use svn as a package manager.

They say that de-facto standard for such things in Java world is maven, well dotnet got a bit of maven too (nmaven and derivatives). I wonder if there is any alternative that have been developed with dotnet platform in mind? I mean for both dependency management and release life-cycle, but not necessarily in a single product.

And, yes, I know that TFS can probably handle at least part of what I want, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is: the open source project [Refix](http://refix.codeplex.com). I know you've found us already, Adlan, as we've corresponded by email since you posted this question. We're in early BETA stage at the moment, and looking for feedback and ideas. Apologies for the shameless plug.